# Birt on Tomcat unable to find JARs

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, tomcat6, java

First, my setup:

- BiRT Runtime: 3.7.2.
- Ubuntu 10.04
- Tomcat 6
- Sun Java 1.6.0

I have a jar file I want to deploy onto the Tomcat server so it is usable by the runtime, so I placed the jar file in **/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/birt/WEB-INF/lib**. As I understand it this is the default location for JAR files that are going to be used by a BiRT report.

But the jar file is not accessible by the report that is trying to call it. In the BiRT logs I see:

> Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: ReferenceError: "DynDSinfo" is not defined. (/report/data-sources/oda-data-source[@id="54"]/method[@name="beforeOpen"]#20)
>    Script source: /report/data-sources/oda-data-source[@id="54"]/method[@name="beforeOpen"], line: 0, text:
>   __bm_beforeOpen()
>   org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: Fail to execute script in function __bm_beforeOpen(). Source:

"DynDSinfo" is the class I am trying to reference.. and now for the kicker... this works fine on Tomcat6 on Windows 7. The same files in the same places.

So is there some additional configuration or some environmental variable that needs to be set, or something different on the Linux (Ubuntu) platform?

All help or ideas gratefully received,

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is from a JavaScript function. Are you sure this is in a jar file? Usually jar file contain compiled java code - class files - only. A war file often has js files in the web folder. If you are deploying from a war, check that the web folder has the js you need.